# How to run few command line sequentially in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am using android studio to develop my game , until certain point I need to use gradlew cmd to build the game and I will get a jar file and later the jar file need to move to the build folder for dex , I find this step is time-wasting and repeating , is there any ways to automate this steps? like saving it somewhere in the project , and one click will do all the jobs for me?

Comment: Take a look over these commands:: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: It's possible to create custom Gradle tasks which can be run with a mouse click or two from the Gradle menu. But I don't have a link to a good tutorial nor have I spent enough time with those to write a proper answer. Maybe a custom task can be added as part of the regular build process too. I don't remember.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I actually did look into gradle , the learning curve is high , can't find a simple tutorial to pick up fast and deliver what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some dig on the solution , I giving a try on console application from Microsoft visual since it let let me execute command one after another and print it to console , also some functionality on moving files to my desired folder.

Below is the method I used in console application that done most of the job.

```
static void Cmd(String command)
{

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };

        var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@command);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        process.WaitForExit();

}
```

This calling this method one after another does solve my problem.

```
Cmd("./gradlew clean");
Cmd("./gradlew desktop:dist");
MovingFileToMyCustomDirectory()
```

Please note, using console application instead of gradle might lost multi-platform usage. Because it only run on Windows.